# Why is column.in_ becoming '=' in the SQL?

Tags: sqlalchemy

```
Query(State).filter(State.c.abbr.in_(stateList)).all()
```

SQLError: (TypeError) not all arguments converted during string formatting u'SELECT states.abbr AS states_abbr \nFROM states \nWHERE **states.abbr = %s** ORDER BY states.abbr' [['AL', 'AZ', 'WY', 'AB', 'BC', 'MB', 'NB']]

I thought in_ was suppose to convert into a WHERE ... IN clause...?

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: what version of SQLAlchemy is this and also which dialect/backend ?

Comment: SQLAlchemy 0.3, Turbogears v1, Python 2.5.6.  I know it's a very old version of SQLAlchemy, but our team is unsure of how many things would break if we upgraded and how costly it would be to fix them.

Comment: you probably need to call it as in_(*stateList) in 0.3.

Answer (score 0):

Try to print contents of `stateList`. 
Make sure that `stateList` is a list of strings, and not something else - like list of lists.

Another thing to check - what kind of object `State` is? Is it table or mapped object.
If it is mapped object you could just use `State.abbr.in_()`.

Comment: stateList is indeed a list.  State is a mapped object, but using an older version of SQLALchemy